ASA - Redundancy ISP in Multiple contexts
At the moment I am interested in the fault tolerance of the route to providers in Cisco ASA in multiple contexts.
As I know, in one context you cannot track the route and change it, but the task is to switch between providers in case of unavailability. Accordingly, I want to select three interfaces, assign three different IP addresses from different providers and write a Python bot to track the availability of providers and change static routes.
How good/stupid is my idea?
What have you used in your work for fault tolerance?
I want to find more solutions for myself that will help me move on.
Thank you in advance!

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa96/configuration/general/asa-96-general-config/ha-contexts.html
Just don't use multiple context mode. The limitations are too great unless all you need is basic firewall (port block/allow) style features with very high throughput. Active/Passive failover is much better if you want redundancy. You don't lose any features that way and you still get redundancy.
If you need high throughput, get a bigger or more capable firewall like the newer Cisco Secure Firewall devices that have full 10 gigabit support or at least a 5585 for 10 gigabit support.
If you have to use ASA in multiple context mode, then do the ISP failover externally via HSRP/VRRP on a pair of routers or layer 3 switches.

There shouldn't be any need for scripting unless you can't use the built-in SLA monitoring for some reason.
ISP redundancy configuration is described here:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/118962-configure-asa-00.html

Zac,hello! I can't use SLA because ASA in multiplecontext mode
